# Изменение двумерного массива в PHP

Tags: php, массивы

Формируется двумерный массив с нулевыми значениями. Код меняет определенные из них обращаясь по индексу:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($list_of_transactions)) {
  $data = substr($row['data'], 0, 7);
  $id = $row['id'];
  $amount = $row['amount'];
  $j = 0;
  foreach($arr as $item) {
    if ($data == substr($item[0], 0, 7)) {
      $i = 0;
      foreach($a_bonuses as $bonus) {
        if ($bonus == $id) {
          $item[$i + 1] = $amount;
          echo "(".$item[$i + 1].")";
          continue;
        }
        $i++;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Но при выводе ничего в массиве не меняется. Однако, если сразу после присвоения,

```
$item[$i + 1] = $amount;
```

вывести $item, то в выводе значение измененное. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Правильно менять так: `foreach($arr as &$item) {...}`

Comment: оу...про эту возможность забыл. не можете подсказать(или кинуть ссылку)почему способ который я написал не работает?

Comment: Потому что `foreach($arr as &$item)` передает `$item` по ссылке, а `foreach($arr as $item)` передает его по значению. Подробнее можно почитать в [документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.foreach.php)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

При использовании **циклов** вида `foreach ($arr as $key => $item) {...}` в переменную `$item` копируется очередной элемент массива. Т.е. цикл в данном случае фактически равен следующему:

```
$keys = array_keys($arr);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($keys); $i++) {
    $key = $keys[$i];
    $item = $arr[$key];
    // ваш код
}
```

Соответственно, меняя `$item`, вы меняете только его, а не элемент массива.

С другой стороны, начиная с php5, объекты копируются по ссылке. Т.е. в следующем коде:

```
class A() {};
$a = new A();
$tmp_a = $a;
$tmp_a->value = 123;
```

меняя `$tmp_a`, вы так же меняете и объект `$a`, т.к. он был скопирован в `$tmp_a` по ссылке.

Поэтому, если ваш массив хранит объекты, то меняя `$item` в цикле `foreach`, вы так же будете менять и исходный элемент массива.

Для копирования по ссылке "не-объектов" в php существует специальный синтаксис:

```
$value = 123;
$new_value = &$value;
```

Теперь, изменяя `$new_value`, вы так же изменяете и исходную переменную `$value`.

Поэтому у цикла `foreach` есть и другая форма: `foreach ($arr as &$item) {...}`. В данном случае, в `$item` не просто копируется элемент массива, а копируется по ссылке:

```
$keys = array_keys($arr);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($keys); $i++) {
    $key = $keys[$i];
    $item = &$arr[$key];
    // ваш код
}
```

Соответственно, меня `$item`, вы так же меняете и исходный элемент массива (не только объекты, но и, например, числа)

И, судя по всему, реализация именно такая, т.к. следующий код изменит массив не так, как хотелось бы:

```
foreach ($arr as $key => &$item) {}
$item = 10;
var_dump($arr); // последний элемент массива равен 10
```

Чтобы этого избежать, перед использованием `$item` вне цикла, стоит явно удалить его:

```
foreach ($arr as $key => &$item) {}
unset($item);
$item = 10;
var_dump($arr); // последний элемент массива не изменился
```

---

**Аналогично и для функций**: указав знак `&` перед параметром в определении функции, вы говорите php, что переменную необходимо копировать по ссылке. Примеры:

```
function simple_copy($value) {
    $value += 10;
}
function simple_link(&$value) {
    $value += 10;
}
$a = 100;
simple_copy($a);
echo $a . "\n"; // 100;
simple_link($a);
echo $a . "\n"; // 110;
```

Не забываем, что объекты и так копируются по ссылке, поэтому если вы собираетесь передавать объекты, то этот знак указывать необязательно:

```
class A {
    public $value = 100;
}
function object_copy($object) {
    $object->value += 10;
}
function object_link(&$object) {
    $object->value += 10;
}
$a = new A();
object_copy($a);
echo $a->value . "\n"; // 110
object_link($a);
echo $a->value . "\n"; // 120, т.к. value после вызова object_copy уже равно 110
```

Хотя разница в функциях все-так есть:

```
function clear_object_copy($object) {
    $object = null;
}
function clear_object_link(&$object) {
    $object = null;
}
$a = new A();
clear_object_copy($a);
var_dump($a); // $a - объект, не изменился
clear_object_link($a);
var_dump($a); // $a изменилось, его значение равно null
```

У синтаксиса `function (&$param)` есть особенности: нельзя выполнить следующие вызовы

```
simple_link(10);
object_link(null);
```

Что в принципе логично: раз вы хотите передавать параметр по ссылке, то как вы будете использовать его после вызова функции, если вместо самого параметра будете передавать некоторое значение?